# How to make a div the width of the container?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I've looked for a solution to this but can't seem to find one relevant. I basically want the div at the bottom with text in (encircled yellow) to be the full width of the container (coloured in red for reference)

Also, the div at the bottom doesn't seem centre on the page, why is this so?

[image]

HTML

```
<body>



    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li id="main_link"><a href="#">Website</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>


    <div class="showcase">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="showcase_overtext">
                <h1>A beautiful website</h1>
                <p>I did ma best</p>

            <div class="button">
                    <button>READ MORE</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="floating_section">
                <h1>FEATURED</h1>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Universal*/

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.container {
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    width:80%;
    background:red;
}

/*Header*/

header {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    font-family:'Montserrat',sans-serif;
    padding:10px;
}

header ul {
    margin:0;
}

header ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding:0 10px 0 15px;
}

header ul li a {
    color:#353535;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main_link {
    padding-right:50px;
}

/*Showcase*/

.showcase {
    height:500px;
    background-image:url('Showcase.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    position:relative;
}

.showcase_overtext {
    color:#353535;
    font-family:'Montserrat',sans-serif;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    right:50px;
}

.showcase_overtext h1, p {
    margin:5px;
}

.button {
    text-align:center;
}

.floating_section {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It [link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-center-things-with-style-in-css-dc87b7542689) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to use absolute elements the way you have. Absolute elements are removed from the flow of the page and thus take on their own sizing. Removing the absolute positioning gets the site much closer to your goal:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: red;
}


/*Header*/

header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
}

header ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 10px 0 15px;
}

header ul li a {
  color: #353535;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main_link {
  padding-right: 50px;
}


/*Showcase*/

.showcase {
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('Showcase.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.showcase_overtext {
  color: #353535;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 300px;
  right: 50px;
}

.showcase_overtext h1,
p {
  margin: 5px;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
}

.floating_section {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li id="main_link"><a href="#">Website</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>


<div class="showcase">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="showcase_overtext">
      <h1>A beautiful website</h1>
      <p>I did ma best</p>

      <div class="button">
        <button>READ MORE</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="floating_section">
      <h1>FEATURED</h1>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Center you *absolutely positioned* `floating_section` by adding `left: 0` and `right: 0` to it - see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: red;
}

header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
}

header ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 10px 0 15px;
}

header ul li a {
  color: #353535;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main_link {
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.showcase {
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/500');
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.showcase_overtext {
  color: #353535;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  right: 50px;
}

.showcase_overtext h1,
p {
  margin: 5px;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
}

.floating_section {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0; /* added */
  right: 0; /* added */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li id="main_link"><a href="#">Website</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="showcase">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="showcase_overtext">
      <h1>A beautiful website</h1>
      <p>I did ma best</p>
      <div class="button">
        <button>READ MORE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="floating_section">
      <h1>FEATURED</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```